# Aborting the Servlet call after the request sent

Tags: ajax, servlets

1.Through the ajax, i sent a request to servlet when the OK button clicked.
2.That request processing some db call and holding some result sets
3.now, when i click on the CANCEL button,need to cancel/abort the request.
4.meanwhile, i need the resultsets which is holding by request.

Comment: Please re-phrase your question, because it is not clear what do you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

There is no mechanism in the Servlet API (or any container specific mechanism of which I am aware) that allows an in progress HTTP request to be aborted (short of a kill -9 which is going to abort rather more than you wish in this case).